# Email last assigned user in list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, workflow

We are currently using a SharePoint list to track assets loaned out to people. Currently, there is an email sent out when the asset is loaned out. However, we are also looking to email the user once the asset is checked back in.

This is all being accomplished through the O365 Workflows so we can send customized email templates.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by creating a Status field in the SharePoint list with values "Loaned out" and "Checked back in" with default as "Loaned out". Create a list item when an asset is loaned out. When the asset is back, set the status of the list item to "Checked back in". In the workkflow, check the status value if it is "Checked back in" then send another email. You need to enable the workflow to run when an item is changed.

[image]

You may also need to put a flag to stop sending emails if the list item gets changed again.